# eb cli 2.6.x initialize iam:ListInstanceProfiles permission error

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I installed eb cli 2.6.4 (AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface v2.6.4) successfully for an app (Nodejs). But while initializing (eb init) and using the existing credentials (AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key), I get to step **Attach an instance profile (current value is "aws-elasticbeanstalk-xxxx")**: and I get error message:

> You IAM user does not have sufficient permission. User:
>   arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/xxx is not authorized to perform:
>   iam:ListInstanceProfiles on resource:
>   arn:aws:iam::xxxx:instance-profile/

The env settings have been used successfully in the past by the app (currently avail and running) so Im just doing a new initialization on a different local machine/OS using existing setting details. Any help much appreciated.

:)